# Malloc calls allocate addresses already in use

Tags: pointers, debugging, matrix, malloc, overflow

#### Introdution

I've ran into a weird issue, I was writting the following code that requestes the user a matrix, the program asks for the size, then the elements in the matrix.

Later, I itrerate the matrix again to calculate the `max` and `min` number in each row and also the sum of the elements in the main diagonal.

> I'm writting this program to translate later to assembly that is why I am using pointers for my matrix, to keep the program as closest as it will be in assembly

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

    int rows, cols;
    int *matrix;
    int *max, *min, diag, num;

    // Input matrix
    printf("Rows number: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Cols number: ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    // Alloc matrix
    matrix = malloc(rows*cols);  
    max = malloc(rows);  
    min = malloc(rows);  

    // Fill matrix
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("[%d, %d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", matrix+(i*cols)+j);  // Store at offset
        }

    diag = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        max[i] = matrix[i*cols];  // Assume 1st is max
        min[i] = matrix[i*cols];  // Assume 1st is min
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            num = *(matrix+(i*cols)+j);  // Store num of the matrix temporaly for fast access
            if (i == j) diag += num;  // If in main diagonal, add to diag sum
            if (num > max[i]) max[i] = num;
            else if (num < min[i]) min[i] = num;
        }
    }

    printf("\nDEBUG for [2,2] value %d\n\n", matrix[8]);

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){    
        for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
            printf("%d ", *(matrix+(i*cols)+j));
        }
        printf("| max=%d, min=%d", max[i], min[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nDiagonal sum = %d", diag);


    return 0;
}
```

**Screenshoot with 3x3 input**
[image]

**Screenshoot with 4x4 input**
[image]

#### Issue

When I type the elements for a 3x3 matrix with the elements from 1 to 9 as the matrix values, the last element bugs and shows the value `3` instead of `9`.

I've tried with other inputs and the bug seems to be copying the value from the 1st row, 3rd col.

This drives me crazy because when I run it with the debugger, the program works as expected.

#### Workaround solutions

The probles solves if I define the matrix as an array (`int matrix[i][j]`) or the `max` and `min` arrays, but that is not the solution I want.

Also if I allocate the matrix with some extra space, the problem is gone. Again, an unwanted solution.

#### Hypothesis

I think that, apart from me messing something up, the second call to malloc (`max = malloc(rows)`) is allocating the array overwritting the previous malloc call, the one that allocated the matrix in the previous line.

#### Note

Thank everyone for helping, contact me for extra information about the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workarounds are on the right track in terms of understanding the underlying issue, it's about space. You need to malloc enough bytes to store the `int`s.

How many bytes? If a single `int` occupied one byte of memory then the answer would be `rows * cols` (which is where you are now). But that's not the case, an `int` actually occupies either two bytes or four bytes (usually four, but it depends on the compiler). Use `sizeof` to determine the size of an `int` and factor this into the calculation.

Thus:

```
    matrix = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * cols);  
    max = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);  
    min = malloc(sizeof(int) * rows);
```

Comment: OMG you are absolutely right, i was just assuming that it allocated the amount was based on the pointer type